# comboBox width depending on longest item

Tags: c#, combobox

i've got a ComboBox that i generate dynamically and fill with some items. i would like to set this control's width to the width of the longest item. how do i count the display width of some text?

edit: i'm using windows forms, but i would like to do it in asp.net as well

Comment: Please state the environment to which your question pertains (e.g. Windows Forms vs. ASP.NET).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends.  Are you using ASP.NET or Windows Forms or WPF?  Are you using a fixed-width or proportional font?

If you're using Windows Forms, you will want to call [MeasureString()](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0300__2D-Graphics/Measurestringanddrawstring.htm) in order to find out how wide you want the text to be.

If you're using ASP.NET, you can do something like MeasureString(), but you don't know exactly what font is being rendered on the browser, so you can't just put that in your script.

Comment: i actually hoped that there is some method that does it automatically for combobox - measureString measures the length of the string but of course doesn't take the "arrow down button" of combobox into account so you have to.

Comment: In that case, the width of the box can be determined by subtracting the Client Width from the Control's width.

Answer (score 1):

See the **Graphics.MeasureString** method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bt8ty58.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set the width explicitly, browser will render it to be the length of the longest item (if the question is about web forms, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Add a DropDown event to your combobox with the following code:

```
private void comboBox_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = (sender as ComboBox).CreateGraphics();
            float longest = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < (sender as ComboBox).Items.Count; i++)
            {
                SizeF textLength = g.MeasureString((sender as ComboBox).Items[i].ToString(), (sender as ComboBox).Font);

                if (textLength.Width > longest)
                    longest = textLength.Width;
            }

            if (longest > 0)
                (sender as ComboBox).DropDownWidth = (int)longest;
        }
```