# C# Adding a long string to combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

In my window application i created a Combobox.
My requirement is like, if i add a long string to combobox and when i will expend that combobox, in the list view that string should come completely.

Comment: my guess is that he wants the combobox to stretch so that it shows the whole string in the dropdown..

Answer (score 6):

Modify the `DropDownWidth` property of your combobox object to accomodate long strings.

Comment: Is there any way to change this width dynamically.

Comment: Yes, just change the value at runtime e.g. comboBox1.DropDownWidth = 128;

Answer (score 1):

Look at this answer [comboBox width depending on longest item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384596/combobox-width-depending-on-longest-item) - it explains that you can use MeasureString to measure the length of the text for all of the items, then I would recommend padding it by at least 24 pixels, and then set the length.